# Correct python project structure and import statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, project-structure, utilities

I understand that this question surely is a duplicate (maybe "multicate" is more accurate). However, I'm asking because I cannot transfer the answer to my problem. Also, most of the other examples given use somehow a "parallel" file-structure. Not mine.

We do have an Utils repo holding a library with some classes and also a tools section that use some of these classes.

```
├── Utils
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Library
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── SomeClasses.py
│   │   └── HelperFunctions.py
│   └── Tools
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── ToolCategory1
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── ...
│       └── ToolCategory2
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── simplify.py
│           └── check.py
```

So let's say I need a certain class from `./Library/SomeClasses.py` in `./Tools/simplify.py` that I intend to execute from anywhere using `py absolute/path/to/Utils/Tools/simplify.py`.

What is the correct import statement in there? Let's set Python Version newer than 3.8 as a constraint. To avoid any hassle, I used symlinks so far, to bring the structure I knew it work. I don't like that solution that much.

I learnt:

**1. The update-path-way**

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.insert(0, Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent)
from Library.SomeClasses import *
```

**2. The relative import path way**

```
import ...Library.SomeClasses import *
```

However, none of these work stable for me (means from the console and on different locations the file is being invoked). To be more precise, the latter one is working if I execute it from PyCharm, but not from the console.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: consider pyproject.toml above root level - should read in structure automatically also will be compatible with python 3.12 after deprecation of distutils. Don't play with sys path - that's dangerous and not necessary

Comment: side note - naming of your python files should be lowercase with underscores :)

Comment: Hi @Drako thanks for your reply. The tompl file I didn't know and sounds interesting. Could you give me an example on how to apply it on the above problem? For the filenames: Is there a guideline available for that? So far I use upper camel case for files holding classes and lower snake case for executables

Comment: Basically - create folder UtilsProject with pyproject.toml and requirements.txt in it. Move all Utils project there as well(including Utils); correctly fill pyproject.toml, then pip install -e . from that top dir and all package will be installed and available in your venv

Comment: for naming - check PEP8

Comment: I am a bit busy now for full answer - if this not help - I will try to remember checking this in evening and providing more details

Comment: Thanks. That enriches knowledge for sure. However, I wanted to avoid a pip install of the project.

Comment: Why to avoid? Anyway you should be using separate venv for project and doing editable install there just makes your life easier and nicer - obviously if you are not already doing something wrong and bad :)

Comment: with regards to the pyproject.toml, the point is to actually *package your project* so as to make it *installable*. Then you can `pip install` it, then your relative import can work, although, you *probably* should just use an absolute import `import utils.library.someclasses`

Comment: well, if you *don't* want to make your project installable (why that would be I'm not sure) then you somehow must hack the path to the directory into the python path, either using `sys.path` or, when you run, you can do something like `PYTHONPATH=absolute/path/to/Utils py absolute/path/to/Utils/Tools/simplify.py.`

Comment: OK, thank you. Why I don't want to install is: The Utils is a repo under development, used for development. It is pulled as accompanying repo and might change from day to day and different versions for different projects. So I'd need the other developers to instruct to pip install the packages again and set up a virtual env. etc etc. It would be easier if I could use the package as is

Comment: But for sure I'm with you, that the package solution would be a nice "final" solution once I'm at a stage where I can call it version 1.0

Comment: You have wrong perception - if its editable install - no need to do anything special; no reinstallation on changes - just when files added, removed. Other developers should be working in a venv per project - they install with -e  your package and don't worry if it had some changes or not as local version whatever they pull from git will be used - they just have to decide on which git commit to sit - in essence its same as installing pandas or similar. You can also define scripts in your pyproject.toml file so certain utilities can by used from anywhere in terminal directly if necessary.

Comment: Then you use an editable install. Otherwise, you are going to have to settle for hacks